# PCRE Regex non-consecutive repeating

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to have a 6 character minimum, up to 15 chars total. First has to be alphanumeric (no special), next (up to) 13 to be alphanumeric and can include NON CONSECUTIVE (and only one of the following at a time) underscore OR period OR hyphen, then last character has to be alphanumeric.

example of okay: A_3.hj_3J

example not okay: F__3d66.K

example not okay: 6-_sd.6h9

This is what I have so far, I feel like it's close but annoyingly off.
What am I doing wrong?

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}([_.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9])\S{4,13}[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}$
```

Comment: Another idea with *word boundaries*: [`^\b(?!.*?[._-]{2})[\w.-]{6,15}\b$`](https://regex101.com/r/zFWXcK/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble: Your regex will also allow `_13.hj_3_`

Comment: @anubhava good catch! I've overlooked this (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of problems:

1. Your regex pattern will also match an input of more than 15 characters.
2. Your regex will also other non-allowed characters in the middle like `@` or `#` due to use of `\S`

You can fix it by using a negative lookahead to disallow consecutive occurrence of period/hyphen/underscore and remove `\S` from middle of regex that allows any non-space character

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?!.*[_.-]{2})[\w.-]{4,13}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eadet3/3)

Comment: The second to last character here makes it fail :( 
a-dFegv_f

Comment: It works, and looks simpler than the other one!
Thank you @anubhava, I've been on this for a few hours and it made less and less sense!